# Find maximum decay rate, given $y(x)=5xe^{-2x} \text{kg/year} $

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

Let the Decay rate of a metal is $$ y(x)=5xe^{-2x} \text{kg/year} $$

Find the maximum Decay rate .

**Solution :**

The decay rate is given by

$$ y(x)=5x e^{-2x} $$

For maximum decay rate

$$ y'(x)=0 \\ \implies 5e^{-2x}-10 x e^{-2x}= 0 \\ \implies 5-10x=0 \\ \implies x=\frac{1}{2} \text{ year}$$

Am I right?

Comment: You still have to substitute obtained x back into the Decay Rate equation, and find $y(\frac{1}{2})$, but yes, you are right till there

Comment: I think **the Decay rate** of the metal is $y'(x)=5xe^{-2x}$. or you stated the problem incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

- Remember to check the second derivative to make sure that it is indeed the maximum.
- If the maximum is indeed attained at $x=\frac12$, you want to evaluate $y(0.5)$.
- Your working is correct so far. Just that it is not complete.

Comment: No , I have to find the time when the decay is maximum .

Comment: If that is indeed the question, then alright (though I would interpret the question as find the corresponding $y$).  Just verify that it is indeed the maximum. You might like to check the question again too to verify the concern raised by MyGlasses.